# How to generate a random number with specific numbers on javascript

Tags: javascript

Guys, I wanted to know how can I generate a number, for example between 5 and 100 but only 5 by 5, for example, it would generate 5, 10, 15, 20 up to 100, but not any other number.

I've tried using `Math.floor(Math.random() * (100 - 5 + 1)) + 5`but i can't seem to figure out how it can generate 5 by 5 numbers and I really need it right now.

I'm still an amateur so please no flame.

Comment: Generate a random integer between 1 and 20, then multiply by 5.

Comment: `i%5==0 ` to check if number is divisible

Comment: @4castle That seems like a reasonable answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function randomIntStep(min,max,step) { 
    return min + Math.floor(Math.random() * max / step) * step;
}
```

Comment: You may want to move this answer to the duplicate question, because this is a great general case solution to this problem. Make sure to explain a bit more how it works.

Comment: Be aware it assumes min = 0, right?